# Can someone suggest any way to complete (if possible) the following proof of the fact that in a not complete metric space is not compact?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

**Problem.** If $(X,d)$ is a metric space such that it is not complete then prove that $X$ is not compact.

**My Attempt.** Since $(X,d)$ is not complete, there exists a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ isn't convergent in $X$ and also such that $x_m\ne x_n$ for all $m\ne n$. Let $\mathcal{A}:=\{x_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

> **Claim.** $\mathcal{A}$ is closed in $X$.
>
> *Proof.* Otherwiese $\mathcal{A}\subset \overline{\mathcal{A}}$ (where $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ denotes the closure of $\mathcal{A}$ in $X$). Which implies that there exists an $x\in X$ such that $x$ is a limit point of $\mathcal{A}$. Hence we conclude that there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x$. Consequently, it follows that $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x$, a contradiction.

If $X$ were compact, since $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subset of $X$, it must also be compact. We will prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is not compact. Consequently it will follow that $X$ is not compact and we are done.

Observe that since $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent, for all $x\in X$ there exists open set $U_x\ni x$ such that $\mathcal{A}\not\subseteq U_x$. In other words, for all $x\in X$ there exists open set $U_x\ni x$ such that $\mathcal{A}\cap (X\setminus U_x)\ne \emptyset$.

Now observe that, $$\mathcal{A}\subseteq X=\bigcup_{x\in X} U_x$$Since $\mathcal{A}$ is compact we have, $$\mathcal{A}\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{x_i}\tag{1}$$But since $\mathcal{A}\cap (X\setminus U_x)\ne \emptyset$ for all $x\in X$ we have, $\mathcal{A}\cap (X\setminus U_{x_i})\ne \emptyset$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

If now $A\cap\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^n (X\setminus U_{x_i})\right)\ne\emptyset$ then we are done because in that case there exists $a\in A$ such that $a\not\in \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{x_i}$, so $(1)$ cannot follow.

But I can't resolve the case when $A\cap\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^n (X\setminus U_{x_i})\right)=\emptyset$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Wasn't easier to prove that compact metric spaces are complete?

Comment: Does existence of a convergent subsequence necessarily imply convergence of the whole sequence? (I don't think so)

Comment: @NicholasStull: For Cauchy sequence in a metric space it does.

Comment: Quite right. I forgot that you had assumed it was Cauchy. I apparently just skipped over that word when I read it.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the step where you say $a\in A$ so that $a\notin \cap U_{x_i}$. It is true that for some $i$, $a\notin U_{x_i}$, but the "Consequently" part doesn't seem immediate to me on first glance. You showed that $a$ does not lie in every one of the $U_{x_i}$, but it's a bit unclear why you can extend this to saying that $a$ does not lie in any one of the $U_{x_i}$.

Comment: @NicholasStull; $a\in A\implies a\in\bigcap U_{x_i}$ implies $a\in U_{x_i}$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ but there exists an $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ for which this doesn't hold. Hence the conclusion follows.

Comment: You proved that $a\notin \bigcap U_{x_i}$, but I'm not sure I see why $a\notin \bigcup U_{x_i}$, as this would require that $a\notin U_{x_i}$ for every $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. I'll stare at it a bit longer. I'm admittedly a bit tired, but for some reason, that step hasn't clicked yet.

Comment: @NicholasStull: Observe that $\displaystyle\bigcap U_{x_i}\subseteq \displaystyle\bigcup U_{x_i}$.

Comment: $\bigcap U_{x_i} \subseteq \bigcup U_{x_i}$ is obvious. My question is concerning the implications. If $A \subset B$ and $a\notin B$, then I agree that $a\notin A$. But if $A \subset B$, and $a\notin A$, then I don't see why it is obvious that $a\notin B\setminus A$. (where $A$ and $B$ are the intersection, respectively union of $U_{x_i}$)

Comment: (To visualize this, I drew a little diagram with two discs, one inside the other. If you have a point not in the bigger disc, then certainly it's not in the smaller disc. But if you have a point not in the smaller disc, it could certainly still lie in the bigger disc.) (Sorry for being a pain, and if I'm just completely wrong, I'll gladly delete all my comments, but that one particular step is not obvious at all to me)

Comment: @NicholasStull: I see now what your point was. Yes, I think that is a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just choose any such sets $U_x$; you have to choose them carefully such that no finite subcollection of them can cover $\mathcal{A}$.  (Also, you don't need to choose $U_x$ for every $x\in X$, only for every $x\in\mathcal{A}$.)  In fact, you can choose $U_x$ for each $x\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $U_x\cap\mathcal{A}=\{x\}$ for each $x$, and then it is clear that no finite subcollection can cover $\mathcal{A}$.

To find such a $U_x$, just note that you can take $U_x=X\setminus(\mathcal{A}\setminus\{x\})$.  To prove that this is open, note that your argument that shows that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed in $X$ actually also applies to any subset of $\mathcal{A}$, so in particular $\mathcal{A}\setminus\{x\}$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: To the OP: The usual def'n of "$X$ is compact" is:  Every open cover of $X$ has a finite sub-cover. It is easy to show this is equivalent to : If $F$ is any non-empty family of closed subsets  such that  $\cap G\ne \phi$ for every non-empty finite $G\subset F,$  then $\cap F\ne \phi.$  So in your proof, let$ F=\{A_n:n\in N\}$ where $A_n=A\backslash \{x_j:j<n\}.$